# How to send a collection of Models to the MVC controller or view using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I have a controller which gets a Model as parameter, but the Model has a collection of another Model. The other parameters can be simply sent using a Form but the inputfield of the model are dynamic so you can add them using javascript or jQuery.

So what I don't know is, how to make a collection of the models from the inputs using javascript and send them to the controller.

*this is what I have in the View*

```
 <div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 ">
            <div class="dropdown volledigeLengte verplicht-ruimte">
                <button class="form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle @dis" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    verplichte velden toevoegen<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu volledigeLengte">
                    <li><a href="#" class="text">Text <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "></i></a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="foto">Foto <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "></i></a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="kaart">Kaart <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "></i></a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="video">Video <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "></i></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="marging-top-voor-fields extraRuimtesVerplicht">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 ">
            <div class="dropdown volledigeLengte niet-verplicht-ruimte">
                <button class="form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle @dis" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Niet verplichte velden toevoegen <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu volledigeLengte">
                    <li><a href="#" class="text">Text <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "></i></a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="foto">Foto <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "></i></a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="kaart">Kaart <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "></i></a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="video">Video <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "></i></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="extraRuimtesNietVerplicht marging-top-voor-fields">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*this is what my javascript looks like*

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var aantalVerplicht = 0;
        var aantalNietVerplicht = 0;
        var matrix = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            matrix[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                matrix[j] = new Array(9);
            }
        }
        var extra;
        var addRuimte = function (e, type) {
            extra = null;
            if ($(this).parents('div').hasClass("verplicht-ruimte")) {
                extra = $(".extraRuimtesVerplicht");
            }
            if ($(this).parents('div').hasClass("niet-verplicht-ruimte")) {
                extra = $(".extraRuimtesNietVerplicht");
            }
            if (extra != null) {
                $(extra).append('<div id="maring-top-voor-fields"><input class="col-sm-10 form-control" placeholder="Geef de vraag" /><span class="input-group-btn remove_ruimte"><button class ="col-sm-2 form-control btn btn-danger "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></span></div>');
            }
        };
        var removeRuimte = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            i--;
        };

        $(document).on('click', '.text', addRuimte("text"));
        $(document).on('click', '.foto', addRuimte("foto"));
        $(document).on('click', '.kaart', addRuimte("kaart"));
        $(document).on('click', '.video', addRuimte("video"));
        $('.extraRuimtesVerplicht').on('click', '.remove_ruimte', removeRuimte);
        $('.extraRuimtesNietVerplicht').on('click', '.remove_ruimte', removeRuimte);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

*this is what it looks like*

[image]

Comment: if you give the same name attribute to multiple form elements in the view, they will come as a string array in your controller.

Exemple : 

    <input name="icase" type="text" value="1" />
    <input name="icase" type="text" value="2"  />

In the controller :

    icase[0] = 1
    icase[1] = 2

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar problem as follows.

- Ensure that all IDs are unique
- Use form tags

The following JavaScript then sends the form content to the server (I have generalised this to include to forms - the original worked with 10 forms).

```
function SaveAllAsIs() {
    // save section 5 summaries first
    var form_section11Data = JSON.stringify($("#form_section11").formParams());
    var form_section11Data = JSON.stringify($("#form_section12").formParams());

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Area/DataSave/SaveAsIs',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            form_section11: form_section11Data,
            form_section12: form_section12Data
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success == "False") { alert("Error saving data, please try later"); }            

        }
    });
}
```

The controller method looks like:

```
public JsonResult SaveAsIs(string form_section11, string form_section12)
{
    SerializeModel(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>
                (form_section11, targetModel1);

    SerializeModel(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>
                (form_section12, targetModel2);
}
```

And finally

```
public static void SerializePerinatalModel<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dataModel, T perinatalModel, int perinatalReportID)
    {
        Type sourceType = typeof(T);

        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in (sourceType.GetProperties()))
        {
            if (dataModel.ContainsKey(propInfo.Name))
```

I have only shown a partial function, but essentially each type is checked to see if it a list, and is so the list is then converted.

Answer (score 0):

> The other parameters can be simply sent using a Form but the inputfield of the model are dynamic so you can add them using javascript or jQuery.

Scott Hanselman has some details on passing arrays to MVC control binding: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Which is essentially: ensure your controls have the correct names: using an index for lists

Although this doesn't directly address dynamic fields, it shows how it can be done.

replace:

```
 $(extra).append('<div id="maring-top-voor-fields"><input class="col-sm-10 form-control" placeholder="Geef de vraag" /><span class="input-group-btn remove_ruimte"><button class ="col-sm-2 form-control btn btn-danger "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></span></div>');
```

with:

```
var count = $("div#maring-top-voor-fields>input.col-sm-10.form-control").length;
$(extra).append(' ... <input name="answer["+ count + 1+"]" class="col-sm-10 form-control" placeholder="Geef de vraag" /> ... ');
```

One caveat: there cannot be any gaps in the numbers - so if you also dynamically remove any controls, then you'll have to change all the names to re-index them (which isn't very nice tbh).

With this, you can keep your controllers neat with `IList<whatever>` and have the framework bind them for you.

Alternatively, just use jquery!